# Unable to create a new MVC project in VS 2010 Beta 2 :( What the?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to make a new ASP.NET MVC2 web site project, in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2.

When I try, there is no ASP.NET MVC2 Web Application option. :(

Check this out...

[alt text http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/9123/22433423.png](http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/9123/22433423.png)

Hmm :( I tried reinstalling B2 (option I chose -> REPAIR).

And it's still not there (refer to that screenshot above).

Is there a way for me to manually add/register it back with my system, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it - I had to 100% *uninstall* VS2010 B2 and the install it again. A reinstall OVER the existing copy did not work.

Fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC2 and Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 are [not compatible](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/19/aspnetmvc-2-and-vs2010.aspx).

Best bet is to wait for the VS10 RC that should be coming out in the next month.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't installed Visual Studo 2010, but what happens if you select .NET 3.5? Sorry if stating the obvious.